# Onde está pom.xml?

Tags: java, maven

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou iniciando no Java e segundo a apostila deveria haver um arquivo chamado `pom.xml` no projeto, porém não consigo encontrar.

Comment: Muda a perspectiva para Java

Comment: Lê esse artigo vai te ajudar http://www.devmedia.com.br/conhecendo-o-eclipse-uma-apresentacao-detalhada-da-ide/25589

Comment: Obrigado M8n!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com a resposta do @M8n alterei a pesrspectiva para Java.

Comment: Mas essa é a resposta. Era só alterar a perspectiva.

Comment: Eu entendi a resposta, repostas que são muito curtas vão para fila de analise automáticamente. Talvez deve evidenciar que 'perspectiva' é aquele quadrinho no canto superior direito que conforme a escolhe mostra informações diferentes, no caso estava como `resource` e quando foi mudado para `java` deu o resultado desejado.